# Android, How to get a view in Expandable list view and apply our changes?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

In my expandable list view i want when user clicks on a child then i change text of text view to other thing. How its possible?

I have this code for getting on child click:

```
expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.elv);
        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                Log.i(TAG, "item " + childPosition + " of group " + groupPosition + " clicked.");

                return false;
            }
        });
```

But how i can have access to its textview? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found, the solution is using set tag and get tag.

Comment: can u please post the solution ... i am also facing same problem